# Minecraft fractional redstone ticks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

What happens when I run a pulse of length 1.5 through a repeater set to default (1 tick delay)? The 1.5 tick pulse is the result of a piston extension.

I would expect the resultant pulse length to be 2, for the reasons below:

Time 0(tick): Piston starts extending, signal is sent to repeater

Time 1: Repeater starts transmitting, signal still being sent to repeater

Time 1.5: Piston finishes extending

Time 2: Repeater converts the half-pulse into a 1 tick pulse, and transmits

Time 3: End.

However, it appears that the length of the resultant pulse is actually 1.
So I have the following understanding of this:
If a half tick pulse gets sent to a repeater, it converts it to a 1 tick pulse, so we get a 1 tick signal.
If a 1.5 tick pulse gets sent to a repeater, it receives the last 0.5 tick whilst transmitting the prior 1-tick. So perhaps this doesn't count as a signal received.
Can anyone enlighten me on this?